# MockBackend, InMemoryDbService incompatibility in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, in-memory-database, angular2-testing

I am trying to implement an Angular 2 and I need to Mock the connection with my server using InMemoryDbService and MockBackend. 
I faced a incompatibility issue between InMemoryDbService and MockBackend. When I put them together InMemoryDbService does not work and I can get data only from MockBackend provider. Should I use only one of them?

Do you have how can I solve this issue?

My AppModule

```
---import all modules---
@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    HttpModule,
    LoginModule,
    DashboardModule,
    SignupModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
    // InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, { delay: 10 }),
    SharedModule.forRoot()
],
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AlertComponent
],
providers: [
    AppConfig,
    AuthGuard,
    AlertService,
    AuthenticationService,
    UserService,
    // providers used to create fake backend
    // fakeBackendProvider,
    MockBackend,
    BaseRequestOptions
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})export class AppModule { }
```

fake-backend.ts

```
import { Http, BaseRequestOptions, Response, ResponseOptions, RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';
export let fakeBackendProvider = {
// use fake backend in place of Http service for backend-less development
provide: Http,
useFactory: function(backend: MockBackend, options: BaseRequestOptions) {
    // array in local storage for registered users
    let users: any[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) || [];

    // configure fake backend
    backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
        // wrap in timeout to simulate server api call
        setTimeout(() => {

            // authenticate
            if (connection.request.url.endsWith('/api/authenticate') && connection.request.method === RequestMethod.Post) {
                // get parameters from post request
                let params = JSON.parse(connection.request.getBody());

                // find if any user matches login credentials
                let filteredUsers = users.filter(user => {
                    return user.email === params.email && user.password === params.password;
                });

                if (filteredUsers.length) {
                    // if login details are valid return 200 OK with user details and fake jwt token
                    let user = filteredUsers[0];
                    connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
                        status: 200,
                        body: {
                            id: user.id,
                            email: user.email,
                            firstName: user.firstName,
                            lastName: user.lastName,
                            token: 'fake-jwt-token'
                        }
                    })));
                } else {
                    // else return 400 bad request
                    connection.mockError(new Error('Email or password is incorrect'));
                }
            }

            // get users
            if (connection.request.url.endsWith('/api/users') && connection.request.method === RequestMethod.Get) {
                // check for fake auth token in header and return users if valid, this security is implemented server side in a real application
                if (connection.request.headers.get('Authorization') === 'Bearer fake-jwt-token') {
                    connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({ status: 200, body: users })));
                } else {
                    // return 401 not authorised if token is null or invalid
                    connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({ status: 401 })));
                }
            }

            // get user by id
            if (connection.request.url.match(/\/api\/users\/\d+$/) && connection.request.method === RequestMethod.Get) {
                // check for fake auth token in header and return user if valid, this security is implemented server side in a real application
                if (connection.request.headers.get('Authorization') === 'Bearer fake-jwt-token') {
                    // find user by id in users array
                    let urlParts = connection.request.url.split('/');
                    let id = parseInt(urlParts[urlParts.length - 1]);
                    let matchedUsers = users.filter(user => { return user.id === id; });
                    let user = matchedUsers.length ? matchedUsers[0] : null;

                    // respond 200 OK with user
                    connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({ status: 200, body: user })));
                } else {
                    // return 401 not authorised if token is null or invalid
                    connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({ status: 401 })));
                }
            }

            // create user
            if (connection.request.url.endsWith('/api/users') && connection.request.method === RequestMethod.Post) {
                // get new user object from post body
                let newUser = JSON.parse(connection.request.getBody());

                // validation
                let duplicateUser = users.filter(user => { return user.email === newUser.email; }).length;
                if (duplicateUser) {
                    return connection.mockError(new Error('Email "' + newUser.email + '" is already taken'));
                }

                // save new user
                newUser.id = users.length + 1;
                users.push(newUser);
                localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users));

                // respond 200 OK
                connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({ status: 200 })));
            }

            // delete user
            if (connection.request.url.match(/\/api\/users\/\d+$/) && connection.request.method === RequestMethod.Delete) {
                // check for fake auth token in header and return user if valid, this security is implemented server side in a real application
                if (connection.request.headers.get('Authorization') === 'Bearer fake-jwt-token') {
                    // find user by id in users array
                    let urlParts = connection.request.url.split('/');
                    let id = parseInt(urlParts[urlParts.length - 1]);
                    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                        let user = users[i];
                        if (user.id === id) {
                            // delete user
                            users.splice(i, 1);
                            localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users));
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // respond 200 OK
                    connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({ status: 200 })));
                } else {
                    // return 401 not authorised if token is null or invalid
                    connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({ status: 401 })));
                }
            }

        }, 500);

    });

    return new Http(backend, options);
},
deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
};
```

in-memory-data.service.ts

```
import {InMemoryDbService} from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
 createDb() {
let user = {
  firstName: "Petros",
  lastName: "Kontogiannis",
  email: "pkontogiannis@accelaero.com",
  password: "test123"
}
return {
   user
};}}
```

Comment: `in-memory-data.service.ts` is meant to quickly play with the framework. If you want to get serious, you should use fake backend to mock post, put, delete, etc.